# How to find out the Activity Intent name from which the user back-pressed (!) to the current Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-preferences, back-stack

I have *SettingsActivity* + *SettingsFragment* + my *CustomPreference* with built into XML Intent for opening settings of Notification Channel:

> preferences.xml:

```
    <my.package.CustomPreference
        android:title="Sound"
        app:summary="Selected: Mozart ringtone"
        app:key="my_sound"
        <intent android:action="android.settings.CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS">
            <extra android:name="android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE" android:value="my.package"/>
            <extra android:name="android.provider.extra.CHANNEL_ID" android:value="my_channel"/>
        </intent>
    </my.package.CustomPreference>
```

When the user returns from the notification channel settings, I need to reread the summary field for my CustomPreference. What is the cleanest and most correct way to do this?

P.S. I only see an option overriding the *SettingsActivity : onResume()*, which redraws the *SettingsFragment* in the case that the previous activity was generated by the Intent **android.settings.CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS**.

But I don't know how to find out.

Comment: you do not have to redraw the `SettingsFragment` in onResume . Just read the value inside `SettingsFragment's` `onResume` .. i never used these Preference View APIs . but logically it should work like this ..

Comment: @ADM OMG!) this is really simple and correct solution, thanks bro)). it works.

and I have an additional interest, is it possible to identify the activity from which you returned via back-pressed?